# Prevent AD users changing the background in Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity desktop

Tags: unity, desktop-background, administration, active-directory

I run a high school computer science lab with 17 desktops running Ubuntu 16.04 with the standard *Unity* desktop rather than Gnome.

The users log in with Windows Active directory IDs and have standard user privileges. They do not have access to the root account and are not able to `sudo`.

Is there anyway of preventing them changing the desktop background or restricting the choice to the standard Ubuntu backgrounds shown in the settings menu? The previous answers I have found refer to the Gnome desktop rather than Unity and refer to previous versions of Ubuntu.

I tried to apply the advice given by @rinzwind and followed the instructions on the linked dconf System Administrator Guide.

I made a directory: /etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks

I made a file called screens with the following content.

```
[org/gnome/desktop/background]
picture-uri='file=path to my background'
```

With my intended default wallpaper on the second line.

I ran sudo dconf update and rebooted but there is no change.

Does this method also work in 16.04 running Unity?

Comment: Use the lock down feature of dconf: see https://askubuntu.com/a/124463/15811

Comment: Offer a bounty on the other post; updating answers are a standard bounty reason.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: I have edited the question as requested.

Comment: I made a complete and working answer there https://askubuntu.com/a/1034238/350004